# Deleted questions and answers visible while on page?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I know that you're able to view deleted questions and answers while you are still on the page in question, even if you don't have the required reputation for this.

But I've noticed that you're also able to view any further edits made to it (question / answer was edited link is still clickable). My guess is that you'd also be able to view any further comments added to it (if that's possible on deleted content, I wouldn't know). I'm not sure if this is intended as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add comments to deleted questions, or answers on deleted questions.

For the rest, edits are still visible because there's no reason not to show edits on deleted questions.

Those edits might even be enough to warrant an undelete vote on the question.